# Generating random matrix in Matlab with value from another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have  `113*401` matrix for example `X` matrix. I want to create a random matrix 100 times so I will have a `11300*401` matrix. The important thing that the value are taken from my main matrix `X` randomly.

Comment: So you want concatenate 100 permutations of matrix `X`?

Comment: Do you want the elements of `x` to be taken randomly (i.e. you might happen to take some elements many times and some none) or in a random order (i.e. each block is a random shuffling of `x`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code chooses the elements of the result matrix `B`from the whole input matrix `X`. Therefore the columns of `B` aren't permutations of the columns of `X`.

```
X = rand(113,401); % sample matrix

% generate random indices and use them to pull values from A
B = X(randi([1 numel(X)],11300,401));
```

Comment: If you have to ask if that's what they mean, the question is probably too broad and should be clarified before you answer. This encourages the asker to write better questions and will help future readers. Since your answer has now been accepted, I feel it's worth noting you should use `randi` instead of `rand` when you want an integer in a range

Comment: @Wolfie True, i thought it is easier to write it in an answer (because of formatting), but I agree that a clearer question would have helped future readers more.